# Akka-Stream 2.6.0+ deprecated actor system setup

Tags: playframework, akka, akka-stream

I used to setup my actor system in the Bindings like so:

```
  implicit val System: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val Mat: Materializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings.create(System).withSupervisionStrategy(Decider))
```

but in the new version ActorMaterializer.apply/.create/.withSupervisionStrategy are deprecated:

```
  @deprecated(
    "Use the system wide materializer or Materializer.apply(actorContext) with stream attributes or configuration settings to change defaults",
    "2.6.0")

  @deprecated(
    "Use the system wide materializer or Materializer.create(actorContext) with stream attributes or configuration settings to change defaults",
    "2.6.0")

  @deprecated("Use attribute 'ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy' to change setting value", "2.6.0")
```

and I'm not sure what should be change in my 2 lines of System/Mat....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materializer is easy, supervision strategy requires more changes.

1. Supervision strategy. You need to provide `decider` as attribute of a stream, e.g.:

   ```
   Source...
   .via(flow)
   .toMat(sink)(Keep...)
   .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
   ```
2. Create materializer this way:

   ```
   implicit val Mat: Materializer = Materializer(System)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's deprecated and it's clearly stated in [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/project/migration-guide-2.5.x-2.6.x.html#akka-stream-changes).

What you should actually do is just create `ActorSystem` and use implicit `Materializer`. As written in the docs, `Materializer` is provided [out of the box](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/Materializer.scala#L197).

In your code just remove explicit creation of `Materializer`